# Can't print tail data from log file to PowerShell console once a variable is assigned

Tags: windows, powershell-5.0

I'm attempting to create a script that notifies me when a Windows application is down by monitoring a log file for specific keywords:

```bsh
Get-Content <file> -Tail -Wait | Select-String -Pattern <keyword>
```

I also tried

```bsh
Get-Content <file> -Tail -Wait | where {$_ -match <keyword>}
```

I can successfully retrieve the keyword that tells me the server is down using both variations of `Get-Content` shown above. I know it's successful because I see the line of the keyword displayed on console. However, when I attempt to assign a variable:

```bsh
$var = Get-Content <file> -Tail -Wait | Select-String -Pattern <keyword>
Write-Host $var
$var
```

It no longer displays the line containing the string on the console

Here's the actual script:

```bsh
$Downstate = Get-Content -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\logs\log1.txt" -Tail 1 -Wait |
             Select-String -Pattern "tcp_disconnect"

Write-Host $Downstate

$Downstate
```

I also tried:

```bsh
$Downstate = Get-Content -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\logs\log1.txt" -Tail 1 -Wait |
             where {$_ -match "tcp_disconnect"}
```

I tried both `Write-Host` and `Write-Content` BTW.

I get no errors when I assign to a variable, I just can't see the output on the console. But if I don't assign to a variable, I can see the output.

Ultimately what I want is to assign a variable to an up and down condition so that I can reference to them in my script when I'm ready to create a logic that does something during given condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach works for me:

```
$infile = 'D:\PShell\DataFiles\so_57360147.txt'    ## my test case
$infile = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\logs\log1.txt'
Get-Content -path "$infile" -Tail 1 -Wait | 
    Select-String -pattern "tcp_disconnect" |
        ForEach-Object { 
            $Downstate = $_
            Write-Host $Downstate -Foreground Cyan ## debugging
            $Downstate                             ## real output
        }
```

Explanation derived from the `Get-Content` docs [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1#parameters):

> **Wait**
>
> Keeps the file open after all existing lines have been output. While
>   waiting, `Get-Content` checks the file once each second and outputs
>   new lines if present. You can interrupt `Wait` by pressing
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Waiting also ends if the file gets
>   deleted, in which case a non-terminating error is reported.
>
> `Wait` is a dynamic parameter that the FileSystem provider adds to the
>   `Get-Content` cmdlet. This parameter works only in file system drives.
>   `Wait` cannot be combined with `Raw`.